# parsing oswiostat

Tags: linux, oracle

I am looking for a way to parse an iostat file and grab the time and iowait. My files look like this:

```
Linux OSWbb v7.3.3
zzz ***Wed Jul 20 19:00:08 EDT 2016
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          49.62    0.00    2.92   13.71    0.00   33.76

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
                sda               0.00    15.00    2.00    8.00     8.00    92.00    20.00     0.02    2.40   1.40   1.40
                dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     


zzz ***Thu Jul 20 19:01:09 EDT 2016
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          10.33    0.00    7.81   20.26    0.00   61.59

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
            sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
            dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

zzz ***Thu Jul 20 19:02:09 EDT 2016
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          10.33    0.00    7.81   20.26    0.00   61.59

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
            sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
            dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

I am looking to grab the time from the first line (zzz) and return the %iowait in multiple files. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The following gets me close, but I'd like to have just the time and %iowait (19:00:08) displayed:
cat <files>|grep -A 2 -B 2 "cpu"

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk`. Choose a pattern that selects the line you want, then extract the field. eg

```
awk '
/:[0-9][0-9]:/ { time=$5 }
/%iowait/ { getline; iowait=$4; print time, iowait }
'
```

This matches a line with `:<two digits>:` and keeps field 5. When it matches a line with `%iowait`, it reads the next line, and keeps field 4.

Comment: Thanks, but this command just returns the value under %iowait each time it is encountered. The file I am parsing has the lines 'zzz *** <DATE>' and the output of iostat multiple times.

Comment: Can you edit your post with a longer example showing the repetition, and perhaps removing some of the `dm-*` lines to keep it short. Also, add what arguments you used for the iostat command, and what OS you are using.

Comment: Edited. It is part of OSWatcher, so I am not sure of the actual command. I just end up with the text files. The OS is RHEL 6.7.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps the awk version doesnt understand the `{2}` syntax. Instead use the similar pattern `/:[0-9][0-9]:/`, see my edited answer with this.